# How do I get this img into my div?

Tags: html, css

I want my image to be in my div to the right with my list items on the left. I don't know what I am doing wrong. It just looks weird. The img should also contained within the border.

HTML

```
<div id ="breturn">
    <h3>Returns Policy</h3>
    <img src="images/Returns-policy.jpg" alt ="Returns">
    <ul>
        <li>You have 30 days to return the item.</li>
        <li>You must pay shipping in order to recieve a refund.</li>
        <li>There are no refunds.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#breturn
{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 500px;
}

#breturn ol
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#breturn img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: It does exactly that, http://jsfiddle.net/by43gbxs/. What's weird about it?

Comment: I just added a width to it to bring it closer together and a border to make it visible. It's fine?
http://jsfiddle.net/gjewqwvf/

Comment: maybe display:table  + direction  http://jsfiddle.net/by43gbxs/1/  or flex + order http://jsfiddle.net/by43gbxs/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/by43gbxs/3/

Answer (score 0):

place the image after the list and set the display for each as inline-block.

```css
#breturn
{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 500px;
}

#breturn ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#breturn img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id ="breturn">
  <h3>Returns Policy</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>You have 30 days to return the item.</li>
    <li>You must pay shipping in order to recieve a refund.</li>
    <li>There are no refunds.</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="images/Returns-policy.jpg" alt ="Returns">
</div>
```

here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/43premwa/

Answer (score 0):

```
#breturn {
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
padding: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 500px;
width: 600px;
}
```

just give your breturn a width it will sort itself out.